# Excel VB Script to Populate a table

Tags: excel, vba

Sorry for all the questions recently but I am quite new to VB. In my script that I have, when I run it on an empty sheet, it runs perfectly. However, when I try to run it to populate a table with those same values, it puts huge spaces in between all the values. Is there something I am forgetting to put in the script itself?

Code

```
For Each i In ddg

        Unit = "Unit #" & i

        LastRow = Sheets("Test").Range("A50000").End(xlUp).Row + 1

        Sheets(Unit).Range("A2:A100").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Test").Range("A" & LastRow)

        Sheets(Unit).Range("B2:B100").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Test").Range("D" & LastRow)

        Sheets(Unit).Range("C2:C100").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Test").Range("E" & LastRow)

        Sheets(Unit).Range("D2:D100").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Test").Range("F" & LastRow)

        Sheets(Unit).Range("E2:E100").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Test").Range("G" & LastRow)

        Sheets(Unit).Range("F2:F100").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Test").Range("L" & LastRow)


    Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to copy values form one sheet to another sheet, based on a specific criteria.  Your code seems weird.  You know you need to fully qualify your from sheet, right.  Try it like this.

```
Sub Copy_If_Criteria_Met()
    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim xCell As Range
    Dim I As Long
    Dim J As Long
    I = Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    J = Worksheets("Sheet2").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    If J = 1 Then
       If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Sheet2").UsedRange) = 0 Then J = 0
    End If
    Set xRg = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A" & I)
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each xCell In xRg
        If CStr(xCell.Value) = "X" Then
            xCell.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & J + 1)
            xCell.EntireRow.Delete
            J = J + 1
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: With the code I posted, I loop through a range of numbers and concatenate them onto a string that corresponds to its table where I pull the data from. I am not sure if this would accomplish that task.